# Openlayers-6 .fit(extent, {options}) not working with options

Tags: ionic3, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have upgrade openlayers in IONIC V3 app from 4.6.5 to 6.1.0. Now map.getView().fit(extent, {duration:1000}) stop working, when i remove the options object it works fine. Am i doing something wrong or anything else is needed.?

```
var extent;
extent = s_layer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
this.map.getView().fit(extent);
//this works fine.
```

```
this.map.getView().fit(extent, {duration: 1000});
//Doesn't fit the extent,just a slight movement on map.
```

Comment: Where is exactly fit? some where nearby? or more zoomed in/out? also there is another method called `animate`. maybe it could helps.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?